# Can't find variable: captureLocalizedScreenshot

Tags: ios, screenshot

I got this error when I run Fastlane's Snapshot tool:

```
UIAutomation Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Can't find variable: captureLocalizedScreenshot on line 8 of snapshot.js
```

This is my `snapshot.js` file:

```
#import 'SnapshotHelper.js'

var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();

target.delay(3);
captureLocalizedScreenshot('0-LandingScreen');
```

Comment: I didn't find any tags related to Fastlane or, one of it's tools, Snapshot and I have not enough rep to create one

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the single quote on the import statement.

For anyone like me, addicted to code stylers, make sure it doesn't change this first line.

It should be:

```
#import "SnapshotHelper"
```